# DB2 Logs export from iseries

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, syslog, graylog2

Is there a way to export logs from a DB2 database on Iseries Power 8 to a syslog collector like graylog please?

thanks,
Bryan

Comment: What sort of log are you looking for?

Comment: Google is your friend...

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Its to see sql statements requested on the DB2 for i

Comment: @Charles If you are a specialist on antiquity system, its good for you but i'm not.. and i find very few informations on google about that point and I dont understand it...

Comment: @Bryan If you're using an AS/400...then yes it's an antique....but if you're running IBM i v7 on a POWER system...then it's far from an antique. You'd get a better answer if you told us what version of the OS you're using and what specific logs you're looking for.

Comment: ok, goal is to set up an alternative to Guardium that is too expensive, i can manage vulnerabilities assessment with other software but i need to monitor all SQL statements requested on the DB, I only need timestamps, full SQL statements and who execute the request. Version of the OS is V7R10

Answer (score 0):

Try

**QSYS2.DISPLAY_JOURNAL()**

**QSYS2.HISTORY_LOG_INFO()**

these are new functions in IBM i 7.3 that were just released

More info here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/Db2%20for%20i%20generated%20syslog%20history%20and%20audit%20journal

Comment: Hello, thanks for your thought, but we don't have this new version. The goal of my question is to trace sql statements, I have try DBMON, but all variables aren't "resolved" and appears as question marks. I will dig around the new functions.

Comment: SQL statements are not recorded in QAUDJRN so i dont think it would be possible via these new functions

Comment: Hmm try and get to the SQL Plan Cache statements then.  I'm unsure how to get that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to log an activity for particular physical file (DB2 table) you can enable journaling for it (which is a kind of db logging) and retrieve tons of details from it. You can find more info [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/dbp/rbafowrkjrn.htm).